# multiple partial string selection in r

Tags: r, string

I need a more apropriate solution for a multiple partial string row selection in R.
I have this dataset with a string column, and i need to select the rows that matches these partial patterns, no matter the position.

eg. i need to find `408050489` in `100408050489a20` or `408050489v20h00j` or `pd020s0408050489`

here is the code that worked the best by now:

```
new_dataset <- ds[ds$code %like% 
"408050489|408040076|408020385|408040068|408040289|408040319" , ]
```

i have already tried the sqldf:

```
new_dataset <- sqldf("select * from ds where code LIKE 
                       '%408050489%' or code LIKE
                       '%408040076%' or code LIKE
                       '%408020385%' or code LIKE
                       '%408040068%' or code LIKE
                       '%408040289%' or code LIKE
                       '%408040319%' 
                       ")
```

but it keeps changing the time i have in another column to 2 hours before.

eg. it changed the row from

> `Code 100408040319200 Date 2019/10/23 Time 10:00:00 am`

to

> `Code 100408040319200 Date 2019/10/23 Time 08:00:00 am`

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Do you only want to use sqldf or any other regex solution is ok? You can use wildcards(eg * or +) or a "simple" `grep`?

Comment: Try: `new_dataset <- ds[grepl("408050489|408040076|408020385|408040068|408040289|408040319", ds$code),]`

Comment: I can use any solution. I like sqldf because it is simple, but it keeps changing the records i have, i don't know why. So i need another one.

Comment: There are workarounds for the time zone problem here: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/10

Comment: Thank you G. Grothendieck, that solved my problem with sqldf.